# Calling Measure() outside of MeasureOverride() - memory issues

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm trying to change the template of a ContentControl depending on the available size to the controls in it. I use a Measure() call on the ContentControl to get its desired size and then compare it to the actual size of the controls in it. If the actual size is smaller than the desired size, I want to switch to a different template. I have the actual logic down, however I experience a memory issue that I can't really explain.

The templates itself are nothing fancy for a start, just a StackPanel with some labels in it.

XAML:

```
<ContentControl>
   <ContentControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template1}" />
       <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Value="True">
             <DataTrigger.Binding>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MeasurementConverter}">
                  <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                  <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
              </MultiBinding>
             </DataTrigger.Binding>
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Template2}" />
         </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Code for the converter:

```
public class MeasurementConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public Object Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double actualWidth = (double?) values[0] ?? 0;
            ContentControl control = (ContentControl) values[1];

            var availableSize = new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);
            control.Measure(availableSize);
            var desiredSize = control.DesiredSize; 

            // Issue arises as soon as I use this:
            var result = actualWidth < desiredSize.Width;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

The thing I don't understand is that as soon as I just check if the width is smaller than the desired size (and the result is true), the application basically freezes and I see a large and constant increase in memory in the profiler until I get an OOM exception. The issue does not occur if I explicitly return true or false.

I suspect the Measure() call is the culprit and starts somehow a recursive call that results in an endless loop, but I don't get why unless it somehow updates the layout which again calls the converter.

Can anyone explain? If there is an easier method that what I have done, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Could it be because you set the `ContentTemplate` in the `DataTrigger`s setter? The workflow could be: 1. DataTrigger is true, ContentTemplate is set. 2. Setting the ContentTemplate triggers a new evaluation of the MultiValueBinding, which is then false. 3. ContentTemplate is set back to Template1. Then start with step 1 again. If this is the case, it would be an endless "loop", and would explain why it freezes.

Comment: @Domysee Yep, came to the same conclusion. The new ContentTemplate changes the ActualWidth of the ContentControl which in turn triggers the DataTrigger again, since it's bound to its ActualWidth.

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that changing the template caused the `DataTrigger` to fire again, since it is bound to the `ActualWidth` of the `ContentControl` (which changes if I change the template).

I now use a different property for DataTrigger to trigger the change of the template which isn't altered upon changing the template.